# Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'. for flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, groovy

I want to generate sha1 for android but facing this issue while trying to generate the signing report from the gradlew it stuck on compilegroovy and builf fails after ./gradlew signingReport

```
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
```

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/samin/Documents/flutterdev/sdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65

this is the stacktrace.

```
* Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
    ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
        at 
    org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
    lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
     executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
     execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at 
     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.
     execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.
     execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at 
     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.
     execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/samin/Documents/flutterdev/sdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:270)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:30)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:87)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to compile with java 21 using a version of gradle below 8.4 (which added support for running builds on java 21). Downgrade java, or upgrade gradle

Comment: Do i need to also change gradle plugin? i am a flutter developer do not have much knowlege about gradle

Comment: My current gradle version is 7.5 and gradle plugin is 7.3

Comment: You can't use java 21 with gradle 7.5. Try using java 17